# Angular JS expression not evaluating

Tags: angularjs

I have written a simple Angular JS code. I'm a beginner. However, one of my expressions is not getting evaluated. Need help. Please check the code below -

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []);

    myAppModule.controller('myController', function($scope){
     // Hide colors by default
     $scope.isHidden = true;
 
     // a function, placed into the scope, which
     // can toggle the value of the isHidden variable
     $scope.showHideColors = function () {
     $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myAppModule">
      <head>
        <title>Angular JS</title>
     <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myAppModule.js"></script>
     <style>
      body {
          font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica,     Arial,     sans-serif;
      }
      div {
       margin: 20px;
       padding: 20px;
       font-size: 16px;
       color:#ffffff;
      }
      #red {
       background-color: red;
      }
      #green {
       background-color: green;
      }
      #blue {
       background-color: blue;
      }
      #purple {
       background-color: purple;
      }
      #gray {
       background-color: gray;
      }
      #olive {
       background-color: olive;
      }
     </style> 
      </head>
  
      <body ng-controller="myController">
      <h2>AngularJS Socks</h2>
      <p>Keep warm this winter with our 100% wool, 100% cool, AngularJS  socks!</p> 
  
      <button ng-click="showHideColors()" type="button">
       {{isHidden ? 'Show Available Colors' : 'Hide Available Colors'}}
      </button>
      <div id="red" ng-hide="isHidden">Red</div>
      <div id="green" ng-hide="isHidden">Green</div>
      <div id="blue" ng-hide="isHidden">Blue</div>
      <div id="purple" ng-hide="isHidden">Purple</div>
      <div id="gray" ng-hide="isHidden">Dark Slate Gray</div>
      <div id="olive" ng-hide="isHidden">Olive</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The expression - `{{isHidden ? 'Show Available Colors' : 'Hide Available Colors'}}` is not getting evaluated but displaying as is on the button. No clue as to what i missed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is missing closing bracket. You can see the working demo here - [http://jsfiddle.net/me8j3zyc/](http://jsfiddle.net/hqg2vap3/)

```
var app = angular.module('myAppModule', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.isHidden = true;

  // a function, placed into the scope, which
  // can toggle the value of the isHidden variable
  $scope.showHideColors = function() {
    $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
  } // <- This is missing.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you havent closed your function

```
myAppModule.controller('myController', function($scope){
    // Hide colors by default
    $scope.isHidden = true;

    // a function, placed into the scope, which
    // can toggle the value of the isHidden variable
    $scope.showHideColors = function() {
    $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is fine, but you have a typo error in your JS file:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []);

myAppModule.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    // Hide colors by default
    $scope.isHidden = true;

    // a function, placed into the scope, which
    // can toggle the value of the isHidden variable
    $scope.showHideColors = function() {
        $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
    } //MISSING
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
<button ng-if="isHidden" ng-click="showHideColors()" type="button">Show Available Colors</button>

<button ng-if="!isHidden" ng-click="showHideColors()" type="button">Hide Available Colors</button>
```